# Excel url hyperlink won't connect

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I am using excel 2007, IE 11, and Windows 7. I am using a hyperlink to the National Weather Service EDD program all last summer without any problem. All of a sudden it quit working. It starts to load the page then goes blank at the last minute. the url is:

[http://preview.weather.gov/edd/?lat=40.2122&lon=-79.7858&zoom=10&ql=TFTFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF&ml=U.S._Counties_(Interactive)|485|0.6|map.layer[us_counties].class[0].style[0]=width_2_outlinecolor_0_0_0^map.layer[us_counties].class[0].label[0]=SIZE_12&bm=Google_Dark&lsr=F&lfc=T&rt=both&rf=major|moderate|minor|action&ht=F&pid=NCR&sf=GOES_Infrared_-_SSEC&ri=1&obs=TFTTFFFFFFTFFFFT&is=1&ou=mph&od=-50&ships=F&cluster=T&radO=0.75&satO=0.75&hazO=0.3&tropO=0.7&ndfdO=0.7&ndfdR=Continental_US&ndfdF=Maximum_Temperature_(ÂºF)&ndfdT=12&ndfdTS=&lviz=F&fullscreen=F&fxt=Point_(Text_Only)&ppd=24&pdy=3&satf=60&obsync=F&owv=F&flavor=Basic&tfo=&tfd=&tfw=&ht=F&hd=F&ho=&hf=null&hb=F&ot=Meteorological_Observation&hvt=F&sht=T&ehm=T&uwl=F&sho=F&ec=F&lll=F&keys=](http://preview.weather.gov/edd/?lat=40.2122&lon=-79.7858&zoom=10&ql=TFTFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF&ml=U.S._Counties_(Interactive)|485|0.6|map.layer[us_counties].class[0].style[0]=width_2_outlinecolor_0_0_0%5Emap.layer[us_counties].class[0].label[0]=SIZE_12&bm=Google_Dark&lsr=F&lfc=T&rt=both&rf=major|moderate|minor|action&ht=F&pid=NCR&sf=GOES_Infrared_-_SSEC&ri=1&obs=TFTTFFFFFFTFFFFT&is=1&ou=mph&od=-50&ships=F&cluster=T&radO=0.75&satO=0.75&hazO=0.3&tropO=0.7&ndfdO=0.7&ndfdR=Continental_US&ndfdF=Maximum_Temperature_(%C3%82%C2%BAF)&ndfdT=12&ndfdTS=&lviz=F&fullscreen=F&fxt=Point_(Text_Only)&ppd=24&pdy=3&satf=60&obsync=F&owv=F&flavor=Basic&tfo=&tfd=&tfw=&ht=F&hd=F&ho=&hf=null&hb=F&ot=Meteorological_Observation&hvt=F&sht=T&ehm=T&uwl=F&sho=F&ec=F&lll=F&keys=)

I can load it from IE and from a desktop short cut but not from my spread sheet.  Anyone have and ideas? It stopped working on all of the systems I have tested it on.

Comment: That's not a lot to go on. Please edit your question to explain in more detail what _"It starts to load the page then goes blank at the last minute"_ means. Like: where is it opened (in Excel itself, or does IE open when clicking some link in Excel?), and _what_ do you see (how far does it get compared to loading in IE directly)?

Comment: Ah, maybe it's only opening the URL up to the first `^`, [like this](http://preview.weather.gov/edd/?lat=40.2122&lon=-79.7858&zoom=10&ql=TFTFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF&ml=U.S._Counties_(Interactive)|485|0.6|map.layer[us_counties].class[0].style[0]=width_2_outlinecolor_0_0_0)? But then the URL in Excel must have been different earlier? Replacing the `^` with `%5E` might help. Or create a short URL using, e.g., https://tinyurl.com/

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved:
It seems that excel didn't like the long URL so it truncated it. That's why it wouldn't load. That site has a way to send the link to someone, and it also has a short link which is a code for the link. I used the short cut and it worked perfectly.

Thanks all.